# Filter while typing

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my winforms app I have a textbox which filters the datagrid while typing (search while typing), this works fine, I also have another button to apply a filter via two comboboxes.

This button does a copy of the datatable connected to the datagridview as datasource, and changes the datagridviews datasource to the copy of the datatable.

When this filter is applied via the button, I make another button visible (called btnRemoveFilterFserie) to "remove" the filter by changing the datasource back to the original datatable.

When btnRemoveFilterFserie.Visible == true it means that a other filter is applied and I want to apply the search when typing on the DS1Filter3 datatable, but it returns an error that the [Description] column isn't found on this line

```
DataRow[] result = DS1Filter.Select(outputInfo);
```

I hope it isn't to confusing to understand my explanation.

This is the code that I use.

```
private void txtFserieSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string outputInfo = "";
        string[] keyWords = txtFserieSearch.Text.Split(' ');

        foreach (string word in keyWords)
        {
            if (outputInfo.Length == 0)
            {
                outputInfo = "(Description LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR `Function Value` LIKE '%" +
                    word + "%')";
            }
            else
            {
                outputInfo += " AND (Description LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR `Function Value` LIKE '%" +
                    word + "%')";
            }
        }

        if (btnRemoveFilterFserie.Visible == true)
        {
            //Applies the filter to the DataView
            DataRow[] result = DS1Filter.Select(outputInfo);
            DataTable DS1Filter3 = DS1Filter.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow row in result)
            {
                DS1Filter3.ImportRow(row);
            }
            dataGridFserie.DataSource = DS1Filter3;
        }
        else if (btnRemoveFilterFserie.Visible == false)
        {
            DataRow[] result = DS1.Select(outputInfo);
            DataTable DS1Filter2 = DS1.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow row in result)
            {
                DS1Filter2.ImportRow(row);
            }
            dataGridFserie.DataSource = DS1Filter2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you doing exactly, what you want and what part triggers the error is not too clear. Can you please start clarifying these issues? For example: which part of your code is triggering the error?

Comment: Tried to clear some things up.

Comment: There is not an immediate communication Datasources-Datagridview; actually, there might be some differences with the indices. That's why it is always recommendable to modify both elements (DataSource and DGV) at the same time. From the code you posted, I understand that the Datasources are re-defined on a regular basis (not the DGV), although the exact conditions are not yet too clear. This might be provoked a coordination problem and thus the error is triggered because you intend to access a record (defined by row/column) not present in the DataSource anymore

Comment: If you include an exact example where the error happens which we might reproduce; or explain the modifications you are doing now or what you intend to do (just "filtering" is not too descriptive); I, or anyone else, might give you some hints. Otherwise, we cannot do more than generic recommendations on the lines of the aforementioned one (i.e., modified both DataSource and DataGridView at the same time).